# How to Like Fan Page instead current domain/URL using AddThis widget

Tags: addthis

By default, when user press Facebook Like button on AddThis widget, the current domain is liked. Is it possible to like Fan Page using AddThis instead of current domain/URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me - remember to exchange %YOUR_ADDTHIS_PROFILE_ID%.

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" fb:like:href="http://www.facebook.com/<Your_Page>"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=%YOUR_ADDTHIS_PROFILE_ID%"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the url attribute to customize the url like this:

```
 <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
             addthis:url="<You Domain URL>"
             addthis:title="Your Site Title"
             addthis:description="">
                <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"
                   addthis:url="<Facebook Fan Page>"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"
                   addthis:url="<Pinterest Profile Page>"></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, just change url :)

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count" fb:like:href="http://www.stihovi.net"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you manually start a fan-page on facebook, you can get a widget provided by facebook. I have a minimal one for a site I own where it simply looks like a thumbs up with the total likes, although you can get a more detailed one if wanted.

In short: Facebook pages have to be created manually, then get a widget for that page to pop on your site.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to use AddThis ... as it allows to share something across a lot of platforms.